# JBossas process failed to start in openshift

Tags: openshift

I cannot start my Jbossas cartridge in openshift anymore.

When trying to start the gear I get the following error:

```
Starting jbossas cartridge
jbossas process failed to start
An error occurred executing 'gear start' (exit code: 2)
Error message: CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to execute: 'control start' for /var/lib/openshift/51b0382a5004462a770000e0/jbossas

For more details about the problem, try running the command again with the '--trace' option.
```

I enabled the --trace option, but no additional hint what is going wrong:

```
Starting jbossas cartridge
jbossas process failed to start
An error occurred executing 'gear start' (exit code: 2)
Error message: CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to execute: 'control start' for /     var/lib/openshift/51b0382a5004462a770000e0/jbossas

/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.23.9/lib/openshift- origin-node/model/v2_cart_model.rb:1325:in `block in do_control_with_directory'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.23.9/lib/openshift-origin-node/model/v2_cart_model.rb:1126:in `process_cartridges'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.23.9/lib/openshift-origin-node/model/v2_cart_model.rb:1288:in `do_control_with_directory'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.23.9/lib/openshift-origin-node/model/v2_cart_model.rb:1148:in `do_control'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.23.9/lib/openshift-origin-node/model/v2_cart_model.rb:1557:in `start_cartridge'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.23.9/lib/openshift-origin-node/model/v2_cart_model.rb:1449:in `block in start_gear'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.23.9/lib/openshift-origin-node/model/v2_cart_model.rb:84:in `block in each_cartridge'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.23.9/lib/openshift-origin-node/model/v2_cart_model.rb:1132:in `block in process_cartridges'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.23.9/lib/openshift-origin-node/model/v2_cart_model.rb:1130:in `each'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.23.9/lib/openshift-origin-node/model/v2_cart_model.rb:1130:in `process_cartridges'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.23.9/lib/openshift-origin-node/model/v2_cart_model.rb:82:in `each_cartridge'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.23.9/lib/openshift-origin-node/model/v2_cart_model.rb:1444:in `start_gear'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.23.9/lib/openshift-origin-node/model/v2_cart_model.rb:1453:in `start_gear'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.23.9/lib/openshift-origin-node/model/application_container.rb:456:in `start_gear'
/usr/bin/gear:479:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
/usr/bin/gear:65:in `do_command'
/usr/bin/gear:474:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/commander-4.0.3/lib/commander/command.rb:180:in  `call'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/commander-4.0.3/lib/commander/command.rb:180:in `call'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/commander-4.0.3/lib/commander/command.rb:155:in `run'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/commander-4.0.3/lib/commander/runner.rb:385:in `run_active_command'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/commander-4.0.3/lib/commander/runner.rb:74:in `run!'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/commander-4.0.3/lib/commander/delegates.rb:11:in `run!'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/commander-4.0.3/lib/commander/import.rb:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
```

There is no information in the server.log file.

Does somebody has an idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try recreating the application to check if you get similar behavior.

Comment: After recreating the application it works. Unfortunately, I still do not know why this happened and I hope this will not happen again. Thanks for your support!

Comment: Secondary the same is happen. Is there another way to fix this problem without recreating application?